# Django: TemplateDoesNotExist at /

Tags: django

I am using Django 3.0.7 and have a project named `starling` and an app named `piggybank`. I placed my `index.html` inside templates/starling inside the piggybank directory
The following `urls.py` is inside `piggybank`:

```
from django.urls import path
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views

from . import views


urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.index, name="index"),
]
```

The `urls.py` in starling (project) is:

```
"""starling URL Configuration

The `urlpatterns` list routes URLs to views. For more information please see:
    https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/urls/
Examples:
Function views
    1. Add an import:  from my_app import views
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('', views.home, name='home')
Class-based views
    1. Add an import:  from other_app.views import Home
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('', Home.as_view(), name='home')
Including another URLconf
    1. Import the include() function: from django.urls import include, path
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('blog/', include('blog.urls'))
"""
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path("", include("piggybank.urls")),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

My full `settings.py`:

```
"""
Django settings for starling project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 3.0.7.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/
"""

import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = ')4^iro*2zhq%f9w2du33eu@ja%)&_cqltplq9b2lzu+qf@xz(6'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'starling.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'starling.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

Template-loader post mortem:

```
Django tried loading these templates, in this order:

Using engine django:

django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: /home/anna/starling/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/templates/starling/index.html (Source does not exist)
django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: /home/anna/starling/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/templates/starling/index.html (Source does not exist)
```

And lastly an image of my directories:
[image: starling diretory structure]

Comment: Note you've shared your `SECRET_KEY` with us -- make sure that you change it before you deploy your site.

Comment: i think in your view you did not render the the template properly. u need to do this: return render(request, 'starling/index.html', context)

Comment: I forgot to add the app to installed apps in *settings.py*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To fix the problem, add `piggybank` to `INSTALLED_APPS` in your settings.

In your `TEMPLATES` setting, you have:

```
'APP_DIRS': True,
```

This is the default, and means that Django will look at the `templates` directory for each app in `INSTALLED_APPS`. In the post mortem you can see:

```
django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: /home/anna/starling/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/templates/starling/index.html (Source does not exist)
django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: /home/anna/starling/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/templates/starling/index.html (Source does not exist)
```

It's not looking in the `piggybank/templates` directory because you haven't added `piggybank` to `INSTALLED_APPS` yet.

Answer (score 0):

You need are missing TEMPLATES DIR

read this [django templates](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/overriding-templates/#overriding-from-the-project-s-templates-directory)

try this

settings.py

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],   # your dir template path
```

Comment: I tried that but to no avail. adding the app to INSTALLED_APPS did the trick

Comment: `os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'piggybank/templates')` would have worked, but since `piggybank` is an app with models, migrations and so on, it should really be added to `INSTALLED_APPS`. Then it isn't necessary to change `DIRS`.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error when I forgot to add the app in installed apps:

```py
INSTALLED_APPS = [
...
   'app.apps.AppConfig',
...
]
```

app is the name of you app, so if your apps name was myApp,

then it would be: `'myApp.apps.MyappConfig',`